# Android custom/compound control: Parcelable state is shared and it shouldn't?

Tags: android, view, controls, instance, state

I have created a custom View / Compound Control in my Android application, which lets users "draw" their signature.

The signature is contained in a Canvas, linked to a Bitmap object.

I want the signature "image" to be preserved when the orientation is changed. Therefore, I have implemented onSaveInstanceState / onRestoreInstanceState by storing the Bitmap's pixels:

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
{
    // Call superclass method, retrieve Parcelable
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

    if (pictureBitmap_ != null)
    {
        // Retrieve the current pixels array.
        int totalSize = pictureBitmap_.getWidth()
                * pictureBitmap_.getHeight();

        int pixels[] = new int[totalSize];

        pictureBitmap_.getPixels(pixels,
            0,
            pictureBitmap_.getWidth(),
            0,
            0,
            pictureBitmap_.getWidth(),
            pictureBitmap_.getHeight());

        // Create the saved state object.
        SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
        savedState.pixels = pixels;

        // Return the populated saved state object.
        return savedState;
    }
    else
    {
        // Simply pass original Parcelable along
        return superState;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)
{
    // Is the Parcelable an instance of our custom SavedState?
    if (!(state instanceof SavedState))
    {
        // No, simply delegate to superclass.
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }

    // Retrieve custom state object.
    SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;

    // Use superclass to restore original state.
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());

    // Restore custom state (transfer pixels).
    this.transferPixels_ = savedState.pixels;

    // If the picture bitmap is already initialized...
    if (pictureBitmap_ != null)
    {
        // Transfer the pixels right away.
        transferBitmap();

        // Refresh the canvas
        drawSignature();
    }
}
```

The integer array of pixels is stored in a SavedState object, which is a custom subclass of BaseSavedState:

```
private static class SavedState
        extends BaseSavedState
{
    // Members
    int[] pixels;

    // Methods
    SavedState(Parcelable superState)
    {
        super(superState);
    }

    private SavedState(Parcel in)
    {
        super(in);
        in.readIntArray(pixels);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
    {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeIntArray(pixels);
    }

    // required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>()
    {
        public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new SavedState(in);
        }

        public SavedState[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new SavedState[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Now, while this is working well if I only have ONE (1) instance of my custom view in my activity... a problem occurs if I have TWO (2) or more instances: when I flip the orientation, all my controls end up displaying the same signature, which was the last control's signature.

In other words, the last set of pixels stored in a SavedState object appears to become the "universal" set of pixels for all my control instances within my Activity.

How do I ensure that each control has its own independent saved state?